# Python remove elements that are greater than a threshold from a list

Tags: python

I would like to remove elements that are greater than a threshold from a list.

For example, a list with elements `a = [1,9,2,10,3,6]`.

I would like to remove all elements that are greater than 5.

Return should be [1,2,3].

I tried using enumerate and pop but it doesn't work.

```
for i,x in enumerate(a):
    if x > 5:
        a.pop(i)
```

Comment: You would typically make a new list with something like `a = [n for n in a if n < 5]`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> a = [1,9,2,10,3,6]
>>> [x for x in a if x <= 5]
[1, 2, 3]
```

This says, "make a new list of *x* values where *x* comes from *a* but only if *x* is less than or equal to the threshold *5*.

The issue with the *enumerate()* and *pop()* approach is that it mutates the list while iterating over it -- somewhat akin to sawing-off a tree limb while your still sitting on the limb. So when `(i, x)` is `(1, 9)`, the *pop(i)* changes *a* to `[1,2,10,3,6]`, but then iteration advances to `(2, 10)` meaning that the value *2* never gets examined.  It falls apart from there.

FWIW, if you need to mutable the list in-place, just reassign it with a slice:

```
a[:] = [x for x in a if x <= 5]
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Beautiful answer, as expected from a core dev. I often see a lot of resistance to the idea of showing list comprehensions to beginners; but I honestly believe that - with a proper grounding - they are *easier* to understand (for the tasks where they're appropriate) than the corresponding loop.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function along with a `lambda` function, which could work better for something that is tuple and not just a list.

---

### Regular example

```
a = [1, 9, 2, 10, 3, 6]

filtered = filter(lambda num: num > 5, a)
print(list(filtered))
```

Output: `[9, 10, 6]`

---

### Tuple example

```
a = [
    ['Data1', 1],
    ['Data2', 9],
    ['Data3', 2],
]

filtered = filter(lambda num: num[1] > 5, a)
print(list(filtered))
```

Output: `[['Data2', 9]]`

Comment: I tried the filtered answer, but received an error:not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'