# Removing numbers that have more length than 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to remove numbers that have more length than 1. But it is skipping one of them. Can anyone explain why is it happening and how can i prevent it from happening in future?

```
a =[3, 4, 5, 6, 54, 43, 543]
for m in a:
    if len(str(m))>1:
        a.remove(m)
print(a)
```

```
Output>>> [3, 4, 5, 6, 43]
```

```
Expected Output>>> [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python remove elements that are greater than a threshold from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59925384/python-remove-elements-that-are-greater-than-a-threshold-from-a-list)

Comment: Please don't operate the list while you are iterating it.

Comment: A more efficient comparison: `if m >= 10:`

Comment: `len(str(int))` may become error-prone if your list contains negative ints: `len(str(-1)) == 2`

Comment: I think this question is duplicate with this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Comment: I agree with @jizhihaoSAMA. You are changing the list while looping through it. I would suggest a safer solution with `[i for i in a if len(str(i)) == 1]`

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA i found my answer. Thank you though. Using while loop with if else statement works better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One line list comprehension

```
a = [n for n in a if n < 10]
```

Or you can replace the `for` loop to `while` loop as follows. For loop gets kinda problematic when changing the length and deleting elements, so it's better to use a `while` loop instead.

```
while i < len(a):
    if len(str(a[i])) > 1:
        a.pop(i)
    else:
        i+=1
print(a)
```

Comment: i liked the while loop approach. Thanks. That was what i was looking for

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your code;

```
a = [3, 4, 5, 6, 54, 43, 543]
b = a.copy()
for m in a:
    if len(str(m))>1:
        b.remove(m)
print(b)
```

Let me explain why the bug happens. For example, if you remove 5th element - 54 in the middle of for loop, 43 is shifted left to the 5th place and 543 is shifted left to the 6th place. So in the next loop(6th), the loop pointer goes to 543; it means that the loop pointer skips 43.

Comment: so it is better to convert it to a set always?

Comment: You should copy a to b and do remove operation in b. If you remove an element from a list in for loop of the list, the order of elements of the list is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

don't edit a list inside a loop

```
a =[3, 4, 5, 6, 54, 43, 543]
b = []
for m in a:
    if len(str(m))<=1:
        b.append(m)
print(b)
```

Comment: i am not trying to append to a new list though i am trying to delete from the existing one